# Private endpoint in apim using terraform

Tags: azure-api-management, terraform-provider-azure

I have created apim using the below azurerm terraform code.

[image]

In azure portal its successfully created. Now I want to create private endpoint connection
[image]

I thought the virtual network configuration will take care of this, but it doesnt. When ever I try to add private endpoint its throwing error. If I have to manually create it, I have first created gateway, link them and then create private end point.I am unable to understand how to configure the same via terraform. I have searched the terraform site to see if private end point example usage is given under apim creation,but couldnt find the same.
How to configure private end point in apim using terraform code?

Update:
Added this code for private end point configuration:

[image]

And seeing this error , not sure why this module is getting this error:

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide the error that you got

Comment: we may need to manually create  a gateway,  update the subnet to disable the network policies and then add terraform code in order to create a Private Endpoint connection. [limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/private-endpoint#limitations)

Comment: Hi Kavya, thats useful information. I have updated the question with the private end point module. And the error I get after running the plan. The variables have been properly configured .still geting this error

Comment: @kavyaSaraboju , I have generated successful terraform plan, and could see that its failing in terraform apply with the error updated in the question. Not sure why clean product starter module is giving error in apim

Comment: Can you please provide the entire code and error in code format masking confidential values ,  instead of images alone?

Comment: I have copied the entire code in the screenshots. I am not allowed to copy from our source code. Thats why in screenshots without exposing the values we use